# Which factor decides the language to be displayed?

Tags: wordpress, localization, themes, translation

I am developing a CMS based on wordpress multi-site approach. So far i have 5 languages and i have created a site for each language.
Idea is when a user go to

```
www.mydomian.com/uk - displays English version.
```

www.mydomian.com/es - displays Spanish version.
www.mydomian.com/fr - displays French version.

Now I have reached localisation of my theme. As mentioned in theme developer handbook, i am aware of theme localisation functions and other options in wordpress. But i am confused, how would I inform my theme to load translations based on site which user is selected. for eg. if user is browsing www.mydomian.com/es theme should load all spanish translations.

Please let us know the best options for this.

Comment: Please read the documentation of [_e()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/)

Comment: Yes, i know this function. But my question is, if a string has 3 translations available, what is the deciding factor of choosing a particular translation. Is it the site language selector dropdown in General settings?

Comment: the 2nd parameter of `_e()` specified which language to load. You can also `setlocale()` to change the current locale in theme header. The default language is the one you choose in Settings > General.

Comment: That's great!! thank you:).

Comment: @Raptor what are the possible values we can pass it to Text domain parameter? is it the translation file name? or language codes like en-UK, fr-FR?

Comment: The 2nd parameter of `_e()` is NOT the language to load. The text domain for theme translations should be the "slug" of your theme. (e.g. `twentyseventeen`). WordPress maps this to your translation files as long as everything is set up correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every site you add in WordPress multi-site has its own "Site Language" setting, so you don't need to set the locale from your URL pattern. The correct theme translations will be loaded automatically for each site just based on its settings.

If you didn't set the language when you added each site then go into each site's settings and change the field labelled "WPLANG" to "es_ES" and "fr_FR" respectively.

The site settings are found under My Sites > Network Admin > Sites then click edit under the site you want, and then select the "Settings" tab.
Or jump to: `wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=<siteId>` if you know the site ID number.

The site settings screen for multi-site isn't as user friendly as the standalone settings page. There is no dropdown menu for the available languages, so be sure to enter the locale code correctly.

It doesn't matter what you've chosen as your multi-site subdirectory or subdomain patterns just note that the codes you're using in your example are not the [official WordPress locale codes](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/).

- Spanish is `es_ES` (not `es`)
- French is `fr_FR` (not `fr`):
- British English is `en_GB` (not `uk`)

Comment: This really interesting :).I will try this

Comment: I followed below steps to translate theme.

Comment: 1. As discussed earlier, I gave correct locale code for each site in site settings.
2. Created .mo files and placed in a folder called languages in theme root folder.
3. Defined function to load text domains in theme functions.php.
4. all translation required strings changed in this format. <?php _e('string','text domain');?>
5. But still translation is not happening. Is there any other steps I missed here.  Thank you so much for you time.

Comment: This is now a completely different question from your original. Post the code of your file loader and paths of all the MO files. probably best as a new question.